# Waking the macbook from sleep

Tags: sleep-wake

How can make my macbook wake up from sleep mode automatically ? That is I will fix up a time for it to wake up and when the time will come it shall automatically wake up from sleep mode. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

System Prefs > Energy Saver > Schedule

[image]